# Circulation for the streamfunction $\psi= -C \ln(r/a)$ using Stokes theorem.

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics, stokes-theorem

Show, by using Stokes' theorem, that the circulation for $\psi=  -C \ln(r/a)$ is
the same for any simple curve once round the origin. What is the result
if the curve does not enclose the origin, or goes twice round it?

This is a question from Paterson fluid dynamics. According to the solutions the answer should be $2n\pi C$, with $n$ the number of times round is.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I calculated the velocity field $ {\bf v} = (0, C/r),$ and hence the rotor of ${\bf v}$ is zero and thus the circulation is zero by Stokes Theorem. But this is a wrong according to the solution. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  f(z) &= \phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y) \\
  \frac{C}{i}\ln z &= C\arg (x+yi)-iC\ln r \\
  f'(z) &= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \\
  &= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \\
  &= u-vi \\
  \Gamma &= \oint_{\gamma} \mathbf{v} \cdot d\mathbf{r} \\
  &= \oint_{\gamma} (u\, dx+v\, dy) \\
  &= \operatorname{Re} \left[ \oint_{\gamma} (u-vi)(dx+i\,dy) \right] \\
  &= \operatorname{Re} \left[ \oint_{\gamma} f'(z) \, dz \right] \\
  &= \operatorname{Re} \left[ \oint_{\gamma} \frac{C}{iz} \, dz \right] \\
  &= 2\pi C
\end{align*}